# Spring Data MongoDB default type for inheritance

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

My model consisted of the following example:

```
class Aggregate {
  private SomeClassWithFields property;
}
```

Now I decided to introduce inheritance to SomeClassWithFields. This results in:

```
class Aggregate {
  private AbstractBaseClass property;
}
```

The collection already contains a lot of documents. These documents do not contain a _class property inside the DB since they were stored before the inheritance was present.

Is there a way to tell Spring Data MongoDB to use SomeClassWithFields as the default implementation of AbstractBaseClass if no _class property is present?

The other solution would be to add the _class to all the existing documents with a script but this would take some time since we have a lot of documents.

Comment: Actually updating all documents is even trickier because the property is actually an array of the AbstractBaseClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using an AbstractMongoEventListener

The AbstractMongoEventListener has an onAfterLoad method which I used to set the default _class value if none was present :) This method is called before any mapping from the DBObject to my domain model by spring so it works then.

Do note that I also needed to let spring data mongodb know the mappingBasePackage in order for it to be able to read an Aggregate before writing one. This can be done implementing the getMappingBasePackage method of the PreconfiguredAbstractMongoConfiguration class.